# On the fly font coloring in Tclsh via c++

Tags: c++, tcl, swig

I am an amateur try to hack together a little project. It is a simple note storage and retrieval console app on Windows Vista (and XP - i'm hoping to run the whole thing off a USB Stick).

I use Sqlite as the store and Tcl/SQL scripts to add notes (and tags!) and also retrieve them by tag. 3 tables and a "Toxi" schema.

So anyway... I want to use it from either a "dos prompt" or more frequently tclsh (NOT wish!) I don't want the windowing shell or to use TK at all. But to help visually distinguish some things, stdin from stdout, notes from timestamps, etc, I want to change the font color on-the-fly with some kind of crude markup.

I found a c++ project that will do exactly this! Jaded Hobo put it up on: http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=9130. Jaded Hobo says the header file "Console.H" is sufficient to include in a c++ project, but he doesn't know TCL.

I found SWIG, the interface compiler, and I'm going to give it a try. But I'm clueless on a few things:

1. Can just a header file be enough?
2. The SWIG Win32 examples aren't as edifying as the 'nix example and they use MS VC++ (VStudio)- I want to use Quincy/MinGW.

   (Oh, btw this is my first ever attempt at using C of any kind. So can you show how to use SWIG with Quincy?)
3. How can I glean from the header source just what the heck to type in my Tcl script to use it?

Thank you for reading this, let alone answering. I started to put it on comp.lang.tcl but I don't like my email addr broadcast like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A header isn't enough by itself. On the other hand, you really don't need to go to all that much work since [this page](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet216345.html) indicates that the API is actually really simple. Here's the C code that you need:

```
#include <tcl.h>
#include <windows.h>

static int MySetConsoleColorCmd(
    ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp,
    int objc, Tcl_Obj *const objv[])
{
    HANDLE hConsole;
    int code;

    /* Parse arguments, first for argument count, then for number format */
    if (objc != 2) {
        Tcl_WrongNumArgs(interp, 1, objv, "colorCode");
        return TCL_ERROR;
    } else if (Tcl_GetIntFromObj(interp, objv[1], &code) != TCL_OK) {
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    /* Get console handle, checking for the error case */
    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    if (hConsole == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        Tcl_SetResult(interp, "not a console application", TCL_STATIC);
        return TCL_ERROR;
    }

    /* Set the color! */
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, code);
    return TCL_OK;
}

/* Standard entry point for loadable library */
int Consolecolor_Init(Tcl_Interp *interp) {
    Tcl_CreateObjCommand(interp, "consolecolor", MySetConsoleColorCmd,
            NULL, NULL);
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

Compile this up into a DLL (it's got no fancy dependencies at all, beyond Tcl itself) called `consolecolor.dll` (the name should match the entry point function somewhat) and then you'll be able to use the [`load`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/load.htm) command to import the new `consolecolor` command into your code, like this:

```
load /path/to/consolecolor.dll

# Duplicate example from the page mentioned at the top of this answer
for {set k 1} {$k < 255} {incr k} {
    consolecolor $k
    puts "$k => I want to be nice today!"
}
```

For a guide to how to pick colors, see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682088%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#_win32_character_attributes).

Comment: Thanks Mr. Fellows - I recognize your name and pic - you must be very generous with you time. I tried quickly with Quincy. I checked the DLL option in the Project but it gave the file a .o extension!
So I copied a tcl.h and the consolecolor.c to MinGW\bin and tried a command-line compile with result you see below. I'm ready to hire someone to do this!
C:\quincy\MinGW\bin>gcc -shared consolecolor.c -o consolecolor.dll
consolecolor.c:1:17: error: tcl.h: No such file or directory
consolecolor.c:5: error: expected ')' before 'clientData'
consolecolor.c:32: error: expected ')' before '*' token

Comment: @klaus: You need to pass the name of the directory containing tcl.h to GCC using the `-I` option. Thus, if that's the current directory, use `-I.`

Comment: Anybody who's interested, I put the dll compilation up as a project on www.vworker.com (formerly rentacoder). My handle there is TclHobbyist. I tried and tried. Either I got error messages or a success that resulted in a consolecolor.o file whatever that is. [Uuuuughhhhh!]

Comment: My vworker in Serbia produced the dll in no time flat and it works great. Thanks to him and Donal. Exactly what I was looking for.